# HTML Image Tags

Tags: html, path, resolution, shtml

I was asked to resolve an issue with shtml file and the problem is like this:

A person was asked to edit an shtml file to add a new radio button. She downloaded the file, added some content and uploaded it to the web server. To my utter shock, the `img src="images/Front_Page_22.jpg` is now pointing to `file:///C|\path1\path2\images\Front_Page_22.jpg`

(please note the Pipe after C- )

Additional Info:
The page that was downloaded contained relative paths., everything was 
`img src="images/Front_Page_22.jpg` `img src=../xyz/images/SomeFile.jpg` or

My Understanding was she did the right thing by not touching the image tags, as they would be resolved at the server and will point to the directories on the server..

I am at loss to understand how those relative paths got converted to local paths!

Additional Info available to me:
Person1 Made the changes on her local system, and after the changes are made, tells the web-master to upload the file

The web-master uploads the file to a Unix server ( the university's web server is on a unix box ) - I don't know whether she uses dreamweaver or sftp to upload the files - I don't think that should be a problem

Thanks

Comment: What tool did you use to edit the html?  What tool did you use to download / upload the html?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of complete info - but I think it was done in Dreamweaver. (I was asked to resolve this problem - I dint edit the file myself )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was most likely your HTML editor that changed the `src` attribute.. Check your preferences, there should be an option to disable it.

**Quick fix --**

Find: `file:///C|\path1\path2\images\`

Replace with: `images/`

Comment: The issue is that I don't have access to the web server. I can only make changes on a shared drive, and they will be uploaded by the web-master. I am aware that I can change all relative paths (images/a.jpg ) to absolute paths  (http://www.example.com/images/a.jpg ).. but I want to know the issue before I do that..

Comment: I think you are right - I checked the source code and saw that every reference was changed. Dreamweaver!!

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the file using save as... Don't! Right click > View Source > Ctrl + A > Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V in the editor of choice. Or do it the normal way, FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have access to the server, your best bet would be to use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). It will download the page and all the other images/css/js files it depends on. [Here](http://seogadget.co.uk/download-your-website-with-wget/) is a basic tutorial explaining how to use it.